# numpy curve_fit with coefficients in vector

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, curve-fitting

Is there a way to use numpys curve_fit (or maybe another fitting routine) to fit a list of coefficients?

I know that it's possible to fit functions of the form

```
def func( x , y , a , b , c )
```

where a,b,c denote the coefficients.

But I'd like to fit a function defined as follows:

```
def func( x , y , A )
```

where A = (a,b,c).

I know that MATLABs 'nlinfit' handles its coefficients that way but is there a way to perform it similarly in python?

EDIT:

The major problem was that the number of coefficients varies.

I found a way how numpy.curve_fit accepts the coefficients in a list

By defining the function as

```
def func( x , y , *A )
```

curve_fit fits the entries of A to the function.

Keep attention, I had to define the number of coefficients by providing a guess for the coefficients to curve_fit

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your problem correct, you only need a wrapper function:

```
def wrapper_func(x, y, a, b, c):
    return func(x, y, (a, b, c))
```

So you can simply pass the wrapper function to `curve_fit`.

Comment: The problem is that the number of coefficients isn't constant. But I found a way how to pass the arguments to curve_fit in a way it works like i want it to.